# Regular expression: cannot end with or start ";", ";" must be separated, must at least 1 ";" but no more than ";"

Tags: regex

may I know how to create a regular expression that have the following rules

1. cannot end or start with ";"
2. ";" must be separated
3. must at least 1 ";" but no more than 3 ";"

Example
1. s;dsdd;sd - valid
2. sdasd;dasd; - invalid
3. sd;dsd;dasd;dasd; - invalid
4. ;dasd;dasd; - invalid

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why is regex the only appropriate tool to solve this problem.  A few lines of code in your favorite programming language could be far easier to understand than a regex (although a regex might be part of those few lines of code).

Comment: @Adam Michalcin - Yes I can split the string using "/" and ensure there is less than 4 array but I just want to try something different.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming perl compatible because you didn't specify.

`/^[^;]+(?:;[^;]+){1,3}$/`

How this works:

`^` anchors to the start of the line.

`[^;]` matches any character that isn't ";"

The `+` modifier matches at least one of the previous type (one or more).

`(?: )` is a non-capturing grouping.  You can also use just `()` for a capturing grouping in this case it doesn't matter.

`;[^;]+` matches a literal semicolon followed by 1 or more "not semicolons."

`{1,3}`.  Braces in the form `{m,n}` will require at least `m` but no more than `n` repeats of the previous sequence (in this case the `(?:;[^;]+)`)

Finally, `$` anchors to the end of the line.

Comment: I'm in the process of explaining it :)

Comment: I'd do the explanation first. After OP nags for 30 minutes, incrementally reveal the answer one character at a time.

Comment: I haven't got chance to test this, but thanks in advance. Just curious how do I "accept" an answer?

Comment: There's a checkbox under the voting arrows, your browser will actually prompt you to accept the answer when you upvote it.  To accept an answer just click the checkbox.  I would suggest going through your old questions and marking a few of them as answer accepted, you'll get more help that way.

Comment: yup I just did~ thanks OmnipotentEntity. I will be looking into your solution but thanks for the big effort to explain to me :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's your regex:

```
^(?!.*;;)(?=(.*;){1,3}.*$)[^;].*[^;]$
```

This regex uses separate parts for each of the criteria:

- `^` start of input
- `(?!.*;;)` a "negative look ahead" that asserts input doesn't contain `;;` anywhere
- `(?=(.*;){1,3})` a "positive look ahead" that asserts input does contain 1-3 `;` chars
- `[^;].*[^;]` starts and ends with a non `;` char
- `$` end of input

The advantages of doing it this way is:

- regex are practically "read only" code, but if you break it up there's a chance you can read it later
- if you change/remove/add your rules later, the regex is easier to maintain if segmented like this

For an explanation of "look arounds" and other advanced regex concepts, see [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)

Comment: I like this implementation with lookahead assertions (positive and negative).

Comment: what does negative and positive lookahead means? and what does ".*".. sorry for asking question that I suppose to google on.

Comment: @seesee `.*` means "any number (0-n) of any characters". Follow link in edited answer to read all about regex - it's a great site

Comment: @seesee What do you mean "doesn't work". Note that by itself, it won't work - if you remove the other look-ahead `(?!.*;;)`, you need to leave the preceding `^` - ie `^(?=(.*;){1,3})`. It needs this because the look-ahead(s) must be anchored to the start of input in order to apply to the *whole* input

Comment: Hi Bohenmian. It doesn't ensure there are only 1 to 3 ";"

Comment: Example: "sd;dsd;dasd;dasd;dasd" is valid too.

Comment: @seesee Ahhh! Sorry! I left out the end-of-input anchor `$`. See edited answer. It should be `(?=(.*;){1,3}.*$)`, so *both* ends are anchored forcing the *entire* input to match `{1,3}`. Thanks for finding this. I'll remember this point next time I write one of these.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest if you specify what you do want to match instead of what you don't want to match. If the things in between your semi-colons should contain upper and lower case letters and numbers, then the following should suffice:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9](;[A-Za-z0-9])*/
```

Read as, match a token, followed by as many tokens split by one semi-colon first.

Comment: not really going to do it. also, the `/` are a perl thing, not a regex thing. drop the slashes when answering regex questions. if it's a perl user, they'll know to add them at each end